# About focusability with ListView and LinearLayout in list row

Tags: android, focus, android-listview, android-linearlayout

The question is : How do I manage to put a listener on elements inside a `LinearLayout`, itself on a `ListView` of `LinearLayout`.

Concretely, I have a `ListView`, with a list of `LinearLayout` in it, and each contains a `Button` and a `TextView`. I simply want to know if the user is clicking on the `Button` or the `TextView` and in which row.

I'm not especially looking for code, but so far, I have a `OnItemListener` on my `ListView` and when I click in, it returns the `LinearLayout`, not the components in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to implement a custom adapter and manually set your listeners for those views(the `Button` and `TextView`) in the `getView()` method. To find the row where the `Button` or the `TextView` was clicked you could first set as a tag the position(the parameter you get in the `getView()` method) and then in the listener find out with which row you are dealing with based on the view's tag. The method `onItemClick` will tell you only what **row** was clicked in the list.

Here is some sample code with the custom adapter:

```
class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context ctx;

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c,
            boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        String txt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        holder.text.setText(txt);
        holder.button.setText(txt);
        int currentPosition = cursor.getPosition();
        holder.text.setTag(new Integer(currentPosition));
        holder.button.setTag(new Integer(currentPosition));

        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int thePosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
                if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx,
                            "You clicked the Button from the row "
                                    + thePosition + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (v.getId() == R.id.textView1) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx,
                            "You clicked the TextView from the row "
                                    + thePosition + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }               
            }
        };
        holder.text.setOnClickListener(listener);
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapters_cursor_adapter_clicks,
                null);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        v.setTag(holder);
        return v;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        Button button;
    }

}
```

I used a single `OnClickListener` for both the views, you could use 2 listeners one for each view followinf the same principle. The full class + layout file could be found here: http://pastebin.com/uM0mb4mq (with *gist* available here: git://gist.github.com/2625797.git)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I must not implement it correctly, but the position attribute of getView() is actually the number of the last element visible, wherever I clic. On what element should I put the onItemClick ? I mean my listView is declared on activity class so and my listeners are on the cursorAdapter class so ...

Comment: @SebastienFERRAND You didn't quite understand my answer, I've posted some sample code with a custom `CursorAdapter` that should do what you're asking..

Comment: Works perfectly when (of course) I get the tag the clicked item. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must declare a custom Adapter to do that.

This tutorial helped me out a lot:
     http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_adaptermodel

Here is a snippet from one of my projects. It alternates between two images inside a ImageView when clicked.

```
 private class EventsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Eveniment> {

        private ArrayList<Eveniment> items;

        ...

        public OnClickListener goingClickListener2= new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ImageView)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.going1);
                v.setOnClickListener(goingClickListener);
            }
        };
        public OnClickListener goingClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ImageView)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.going2);
                v.setOnClickListener(goingClickListener2);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitemlayout, null);

                }
                if (items==null) return v;

                Eveniment ev = items.get(position);
                if (ev != null) { //init for each listItem
                        TextView tv_Titlu = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Titlu);
                        TextView tv_eventBody = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_eventBody);
                        ImageView iv_EventPic = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iv_eventPic);
                        ImageView iv_going = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iv_going);

                        iv_going.setOnClickListener(goingClickListener);//setting the onClickListener

                        tv_Titlu.setText(ev.getEvent());

                        ... //other initialization for each view in my layout
                }
                return v;
        }
```

In the above example getView() is called for each listItem. I get access to my ImageVeiw by calling findViewById() on the view v ( a RelativeLayout inside each listItem )

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I use a custom CursorAdapter, but still I don't get how to know the position in the listView of my the element inside a linearLayout which was clicked, even on the tutorial.